# Wordpress Custom Login Form which stores the data as well as emails the field values

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email, registration

If the above title looks confusing then here is the description....

I have a template page where I have placed the wordpress default registration form. Now what exactly I want is to add few extra fields on that form.
The wordpress registration will go on as it is. I mean the username and email and password gets stored on the database but along with that new fields or extra details like phone/address/age etc etc gets emailed to a specific email id.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" class="wp-user-form">
            <div class="username">
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e('Username'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="user_login" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_login)); ?>" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="101" />
            </div>
            <div class="password">
                <label for="user_email"><?php _e('Your Email'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="user_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_email)); ?>" size="25" id="user_email" tabindex="102" />
            </div>
            <div class="login_fields">
                <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>
                <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php _e('Sign up!'); ?>" class="user-submit" tabindex="103" />
                <?php $register = $_GET['register']; if($register == true) { echo '<p>Check your email for the password!</p>'; } ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?register=true" />
                <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Note:- The new fields aren't added here.

Is it possible? If yes, then how? Should I add a second form below this form which fires the email? Kindly please suggest an appropriate solution for this.